# R: XML to data-frame: with sub-columns

Tags: xml, r

I have a rather simple XML data to parse in R, the only issue is that for every observation, one variable is presented in sub-variables, i.e.:

```
<item>
  <location>Memphis, TN</location>
  <bidLevel value="Bid Level">
     <lowPrice>2.76</lowPrice>
     <highPrice>2.78</highPrice>
  </bidLevel>
</item>
```

This means that a simple xmlToDataFrame won't work: it would collapse the two bidLevel columns into one. The solution I found was to convert to a list instead of a df, "unlist" each element, and then bind them again, which is certainly not very elegant (and rather slow). Is there anything more elegant?

my solution:

```
library(httr)
library(XML)


url_small <- "https://www.marketnews.usda.gov/mnp/ls-report?&endDateGrain=01/02/2001&commDetail=SOFT+RED+WINTER~NONE~US+NO+2&repMonth=1&endDateWeekly=&repType=Daily&rtype=&fsize=&_use=1&use=&_fsize=1&byproducts=&run=Run&pricutvalue=&repDateGrain=01/01/2001&runReport=true&grade=&regionsDesc=Chicago,+IL,+St.+Louis,+MO,+Cincinnati,+OH,+Toledo,+OH,+Memphis,+TN&subprimals=&mscore=&endYear=2015&repDateWeekly=&_wrange=1&endDateWeeklyGrain=&repYear=2015&loc=Chicago,+IL&loc=St.+Louis,+MO&loc=Cincinnati,+OH&loc=Toledo,+OH&loc=Memphis,+TN&_loc=1&wrange=&_grade=1&repDateWeeklyGrain=&_byproducts=1&organic=NO&category=Grain&_mscore=1&subComm=Wheat&commodity=Coarse&_commDetail=1&_subprimals=1&cut=&endMonth=1&repDate=01/01/2001&endDate=01/02/2001&format=xml"
get_2000 <- GET(URLencode(url_small))

li_i <- xmlToList(content(get_2000))
df_i <- do.call("rbind", lapply(li_i , unlist))
```

Thanks!

Comment: Since technically this is not a question since you already have a solution but want elegance or optimization, consider posting this in SE's [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).